# iPhone Viewport cut-off - this must be a common issue?

Tags: css, iphone, viewport

Morning all,

I need assistance with iPhone viewport issues. I have sifted through all kinds of posts, all from 8+ years ago. Some had a similar issue, some had the exact issue. Seems none actually found a fix.

I have developed a site and cannot for the life of me work out why only on iPhone the viewport is cutting off the left of the content. The site works as expected on android, macbook and desktop. I do not have access to an iPad. All completely responsive. When I say "cut-off" I mean you cannot scroll to the left at all.

I tested on an iPhone 8 and thought, ok, it is a bit old, probably just limited to older phones but alas, when I checked with friends on an iPhone X and 11 pro they both had the same issue. It is not an issue in landscape, only portrait.

Please see below screenshots:

[Iphone issue where you can see that the content is shifted to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzfEJ.jpg)

[Galaxy S10 where you can see the content is centered as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdkRF.jpg)

As you can see from the above, it is like the phones are readying the viewport size correctly but they are shifting the content to the left. The banner at the top is set to width: 100%; and yet it does not stretch to the far right.

Also, bizarrely it seems that the nav is happily centered but all other content is not.

I am at a loss.

This must be a common issue with an easy fix that just isn't asked, I hope. I have built this using purely CSS and HTML so nothing fancy.

Entire code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568325/iphone-8-viewport-cuts-off-text-yet-site-is-responsive-to-smaller-viewports) in my previously unanswered post which had a little less detail.

[link to the site](https://dazzling-beaver-b23845.netlify.app)

Comment: Please look at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20for%20Teams%20is%20a%20private,%20secure,to%20ensuring%20your%20code%20that%20reproduces%20the and give us some minimal code snippet that shows the problem otherwise we'll just be guessing.

Comment: Done. Many thanks!

Comment: Not a minimal reproducible piece of code, but nonetheless I've had a look at the code on your previous question (It would be better to ask just one question, with a proper example so we can help you and be more focused) . There's several bits of CSS there (-webkit-box-...) which are non standard and are deprecated and are you sure they don't clash with more standard flex settings? See MDN for more info.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to using SCSS. I wouldn't even know where to start debugging that. Apart from the partials and variables I don't quite know why SCSS is a thing. It seems it applies some form of webkit code to as much as it can and I do not understand why that would be. I'll probably just re-write the whole thing without scss to see if it works that way. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Hi, I didn't know SCSS was involved (it may be being used, but can't see it in what you have given). What I'm saying is can you take out all the deprecated CSS stuff and see what happens?

Comment: Hi A Haworth, So I actually just rewrote the site removing all the SCSS applied webkits and anything not base CSS. This didn't help but it pointed me in the direction of the "intro-section". Would you believe it was the <hr> tag that was causing the issue. As soon as I removed this there was no issue on iPhone. Do you have any ideas as to why this may be? Just out of curiousity more than anyting. Looks like I can go back to using SCSS again. Phew. Thanks for all of your efforts too.

Comment: Sorry to put you to all that trouble! But glad you found the problem. It is a bit weird. It sounds as though it would be worth your putting up an answer just showing the line or so of code which caused the problem as it might help someone else later on (you are allowed to put up an answer to your own question).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future looking into this or a similar issue, it seems that iPhone's have challenges interpreting

---

tags. This is not limited to Safari as I tested the code on Opera and firefox on an iPhone 8 and iPhone X and the same issue occured.

Not only did the CSS applied to the

---

tag not take effect on the iPhone but it created some form of break in the page entirely.

---

tags are a little outdated as I understand however it added a nice aesthetic. Instead I created the same visual effect by entirely removing the

---

tag and using bottom-border on the SVG.

I hope this helps someone in the future.